# UnimplementedError: "Cast string to float is not supported" | Function call stack: predict_function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to do multivariate time series forecasting, but when I call `model.predict(input_x, verbose=1)` it returns

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node sequential_5/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-6-ebf024c56d89>:111) ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_78009]

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

However, when I print out `input_x` and `type(input_x)` I get

```
[[['Signal_1']
  ['Signal_2']
  ['Signal_3']
  ['Signal_4']
  ['Signal_5']]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Which, according to [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict), should be a acceptable form of input:

> Input samples. It could be:
> A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs)

Comment: are you sure the input is a number

Comment: What does 'Signal_1' represent?  Just a string?  or is it supposed to to be an array name or even file name?

Comment: The names Signal 1-5 are the column names of the CSV-data I want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input has to be integer array, you need encode string input to integer